# getting setgid:Operation not permitted error while running 'su' command - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sudo, 12.04

I am logged in with imp user. And when I am trying to login via root user on terminal:

```
impuser@machine:~$ su - root
```

it gives:

```
setgid:Operation not permitted
```

any idea,How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You're using ubuntu, so you want sudo, not su.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu only allows `sudo` to increase privilege level, not `su` (unlike other distros). To get a `root` shell, try this:

```
sudo su
```

Comment: The canonical way is to use `sudo bash` or whatever shell is your favorite

Comment: Ubuntu runs `su` just fine (which is easily proved by seeing that `sudo su` works), and does so like any other distro. What Ubuntu does not do is set a password for root by default. The reason `sudo su` works is that `su` is configured by default to not prompt for a password if it's run by root. That is also why this is the wrong way to do it - `sudo` already runs as root, so `su` is redundant (and undesireable for other reasons well-documented elsewhere). The "right" way to do this is, as @kervin noted, either `sudo -i` or `sudo -s`, optionally followed by the shell you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -i
```

For an interactive root shell.  This has the benefit of also processing the .login and .profile scripts.

```
sudo -s
```

Will also give you a root shell but it will not process the root login scripts.

Answer (score -1):

If "impuser" is allowed to get root ( that means that he is not excluded from sudo rights in the `/etc/sudoers` file ) Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo su
```