# sudo su fails with 'Unable to change to sudoers gid :operation not permitted.' fault

Tags: password, sudo, root, authentication

I have installed ubuntu and now I want to install flex. It asks for password but when I type my password, it asks me the password for root.

When I enter the password which I had specified during installation, it says, "Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful. Please try again."

Whether the password for root is locked or is it something else?
The passwords I entered were correct.

I have also tried `sudo su` but it says, "Unable to change to sudoers gid :operation not permitted."

I have tried su also but when I enter the password it says, "Authentication failure".

Please help me out. I thought that maybe this is because the root user is locked by default. If so, how to recover from it? And if something else is the issue then what to do?

Comment: In a terminal, `sudo su` is not working either?

Comment: What command are you trying to run? Did you try running the command with sudo instead of becoming root with su then running the command?

Comment: sudo was also giving problem. i have re installed with diff. wubi.i thought problem was with wubi of 13.04 .now every thing works fine. thanks.i got solution on http://askubuntu.com/questions/283950/mountcant-read-proc-mounts

Comment: For voters: see OP's comment on 1st answer.

Answer (score 3):

The command you're looking for is `sudo -s`.  You can also accomplish the same thing with `sudo bash`

`su` and `sudo su` doesn't work on Ubuntu for security reasons.  It fails because the `root` user does not have a password, and those operations are you attempting to "log in" as user `root`

Comment: `sudo su` sure does work, it's just a bit silly to run `sudo` to run `su`, when you can just run `sudo -s` if you want a shell as root.

Comment: I found the answer. the problem was with wubi.i have re installed with wubi12.04. and working fine.

Comment: @usmangani just a tip, don't use wubi. It is not supported any more and causes more problems than it solves. Just install Ubuntu the regular way for the best experience (and more speed).

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then log in and run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /home/user/.*
```

Where `user` is your user name, for example `qasim:qasim`.

Find further help here:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2065472
- [getting setgid:Operation not permitted error while running 'su' command - Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178125/getting-setgidoperation-not-permitted-error-while-running-su-command-ubuntu)

Comment: solution on http://askubuntu.com/questions/283950/mountcant-read-proc-mounts

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 got me to a console login.  I wasn't able to log into the GUI using root, and su/sudo wouldn't work from the guest login.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "#" before

```
/usr/bin/sudo Ux,
```

in

/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/launchpad-integration

and i also removed the "#" from

```
#include <tunables/global>
#include <abstractions/lightdm>
#include <abstractions/lightdm_chromium-browser>
```

in /etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session

but i don't know if all of this is necessary