# Find which package is causing this message "setpriv: setresgid failed: Operation not permitted"

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

Whenever I run `sudo apt upgrade` and there are packages being upgraded I get this message `setpriv: setresgid failed: Operation not permitted` as part of the output.

How can I find which package is causing it and how can I fix this.

BTW, What is apt trying to set here with `setpriv` and what is
`setresgid`?

**Edit**

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 as proot on termux (terminal) on an Android device.

I have seen the answers at [getting setgid:Operation not permitted error while running 'su' command - Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178125/getting-setgidoperation-not-permitted-error-while-running-su-command-ubuntu) It didn't;t help me since I am not trying tto become root. i'n only running apt upgrade with sudo. At keast as much as I understand there is a difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting setgid:Operation not permitted error while running 'su' command - Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178125/getting-setgidoperation-not-permitted-error-while-running-su-command-ubuntu)

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; so we're somewhat limited to *generic* advice that will likely work on all. For the most specific & helpful advice, it's best if we're told what you're actually using.  *Given I don't know what you're using, I can't even explore those answers to check they apply for your unstated product/release; thus as you know you can adjust as appropriate*

Comment: @guiverc updated my question to provide OS/release and why I think your suggested question didn't work fir me.